# "global name 'forloop' is not defined "in django view :ERROR

Tags: python

```
for hotel in hotels:
     if xyz:
       if forloop.counter <= 3:
        similar_venues.append(hotel)
        break;
```

its giving me the below error:
global name 'forloop' is not defined

Comment: Just curious about why you expected `forloop` to exist; is there another language or framework that provides something similar?

Comment: because in the django template when I did that I worked fine... something like this {{forloop.parentloop.counter}} so i expected it would work the same in a view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python doesn't automatically create a for-loop counter, you have to do that yourself.

You can do that using [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
for counter, hotel in enumerate(hotels):
     if xyz:
       if counter <= 3:
        similar_venues.append(hotel)
        break
```

(Also the 'if' conditions can be combined like so: `if xyz and counter <= 3:` If the first condition is false, the second condition won't be tested.)